# Does closure create a strong reference to an object that is created inside closure scope?

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, memory-leaks

In this example, will vm and targetVC get deinitialized? will it cause a memory leak?

```
loginModule.checkbox.checkboxAction = { [unowned self] in
   let vm = HomeViewModel()
   let targetVC = HomeViewController(viewModel: vm)
   navigationController?.setViewControllers([targetVC], animated: true)
 }
```

Comment: I should say it's also `[unowned self]` when you are not actually using `self` inside the closure has no effect. And a use of `unowned` here (as opposed to `weak`) is a bit strange too. Don't you want to check that `self` is actually there, as opposed to crashing the app if self was deallocated? And don't you want to make sure you actually launch the VC only if `self` is still there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither `vm` and `targetVC` are captured, because they’re defined with the closure. They like any ol’ local variable.

- `vm` won’t be deinitialized, because the new `HomeViewController` keeps a reference to it (I’m assuming it’s a strong references, because it wouldn’t make sense otherwise.
- `targetVC` probably won’t get deintialized, because `navigationController` will be holding a reference to it. There is an oddity here though, that the `navigationController` is optional, so this set will only happen if it’s not nil. It being optional is weird, and probably improper. It should have been unwrapped earlier.